# The all.equal function gives a false positive

Tags: r

I found what it might seem a bug in the `all.equal` function that seems to give false positive results. Here is a small reproducible example:

```
a<-rep(1,1e7)
#create a second vector in which each element is almost equal to a
b<-a + .Machine$double.eps
#as expected a and b are "all.equal"
all.equal(a,b)
#[1] TRUE
#Now we set a slighty different value for the first element of b
b[1]<-1.1
all.equal(a,b)
#[1] TRUE
```

How is that? Why the `TRUE` result even if the difference between `a[1]` and `b[1]` is well above the tolerance value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, this is the intended behaviour of the `all.equal` function. To understand better the matter, here is a small recap of what `all.equal` mainly does.

- For first, it checks the attributes of the two objects to compare. Of course, if the `check.attributes` is set to `FALSE`, this step is skipped.
- Then, it checks whether `NA`s values correspond in both `current` and `target`. If they don't, the function exits and a proper message is returned.
- Next, the elements which are **exactly** equal are removed.
- The average of the absolute differences of the remaining values is evaluated. If this average is less than the `tolerance` , the function returns `TRUE`; otherwise a string with the mean difference is returned.

The last step is the crucial one. `all.equal` doesn't check whether all the differences are below the tolerance level. It checks whether the **mean** of the (absolute) differences  is. This could create what it might seem a false positive. In your case, all the elements of `a` and `b` are different; the small difference of the first element (0.1) is divided by the number of the different values, which is very large. It ends up being a number lower than the default tolerance.

It has to be stressed that these "false positives" can arise only in fringe cases like the one OP posted.